# How can I shorten a type in the body of a function

Tags: julia

Best be explained by an example:

I define a type

```
type myType
    α::Float64
    β::Float64
end
z = myType( 1., 2. )
```

Then suppose that I want to pass this type as an argument to a function:

```
myFunc( x::Vector{Float64}, m::myType ) =
    x[1].^m.α+x[2].^m.β
```

Is there a way to pass `myType` so that I can actually use it in the body of the function in a "cleaner" fashion as follows:

```
    x[1].^α+x[2].^β
```

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Note: the Julia convention for types is to have a starting caps for types, i.e. MyType instead of myType. You don't have to follow this if you don't want to, just informing you of [the Julia style guide](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/style-guide/).

Comment: hah, I like how the style guide still advises the use of `cell(n)` even though they went ahead and deprecated it :p

Comment: That link points to the style guide for v0.4. When `cell` was deprecated the style guide was updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use dispatch to a more general function:

```
myFunc( x::Vector{Float64}, α::Float64, β::Float64) = x[1].^α+x[2].^β
myFunc( x::Vector{Float64}, m::myType = myFunc(x,m.α,m.β)
```

Or if your functions are longer, you may want to use Parameters.jl's `@unpack`:

```
function myFunc( x::Vector{Float64}, m::myType )
  @unpack m: α,β #now those are defined
  x[1].^α+x[2].^β
end
```

The overhead of unpacking is small because you're not copying, it's just doing a bunch of `α=m.α` which is just making an `α` which points to `m.α`. For longer equations, this can be a much nicer form if you have many fields and use them in long calculations (for reference, I use this a lot in DifferentialEquations.jl).

### Edit

There's another way as noted in the comments. Let me show this. You can define your type (with optional kwargs) using the `@with_kw` macro from Parameters.jl. For example:

```
using Parameters
@with_kw type myType
  α::Float64 = 1.0 # Give a default value
  β::Float64 = 2.0 
end
z = myType() # Generate with the default values
```

Then you can use the `@unpack_myType` macro which is automatically made by the `@with_kw` macro:

```
function myFunc( x::Vector{Float64}, m::myType )
  @unpack_myType m
  x[1].^α+x[2].^β
end
```

Again, this only has the overhead of making the references α and β without copying, so it's pretty lightweight.

Comment: Nice. Especially the dispatch approach, nice hack! However, I get the impression the question isn't for the specific case of having an α and β, but rather the conceptual equivalent of "from numpy import *", where you can't specify the fieldnames manually. Does @unpack have the ability to unpack the entire object without specifying fieldnames?

Comment: Yes. [The documentation](http://parametersjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/) explains that there's a magic little `@unpack_MyType` which will be already defined if you defined your type with `@with_kw`. Then you just do `@unpack_MyType m` and it will unpack the type.

Comment: Nice, good to know. I'd update the answer with that last bit then, that seems to be pretty much what OP wants. :)

Comment: Excellent @ChrisRackauckas this is precisely what I was aiming at, many thanks to everyone who took the time to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to the body of your function:

```
(α::Float64, β::Float64) = (m.α, m.β)
```

Comment: Thank you - but is there another way to do it, a way that is more convenient when the type is comprised of many elements?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: My original answer was wrong for a subtle reason, but I thought it was a very interesting bit of information so rather than delete it altogether, I'm leaving it with an explanation on why it's wrong. Many thanks to Fengyang for pointing out the global scope of eval! (as well as the use of `$` in an Expr context!)

The original answer suggested that:

```
[eval( parse( string( i,"=",getfield( m,i)))) for i in fieldnames( m)]
```

would return a list comprehension which had assignment side-effects, since it conceptually would result in something like `[α=1., β=2., etc]`. The assumption was that this assignment would be within local scope. However, as pointed out, `eval` is always assessed at *global* scope, therefore the above one-liner does not do what it's meant to. Example:

```
julia> type MyType
         α::Float64
         β::Float64
       end

julia> function myFunc!(x::Vector{Float64}, m::MyType)
         α=5.; β=6.; 
         [eval( parse( string( i,"=",getfield( m,i)))) for i in fieldnames( m)]
         x[1] = α; x[2] = β; return x
       end;

julia> myFunc!([0.,0.],MyType(1., 2.))
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 5.0
 6.0

julia> whos()
                        MyType    124 bytes  DataType
                        myFunc      0 bytes  #myFunc
                             α      8 bytes  Float64
                             β      8 bytes  Float64
```

I.e. as you can see, the intention was for the local variables α and β to be overwritten, but they didn't; eval placed α and β variables at global scope instead. As a matlab programmer I naively assumed that `eval()` was conceptually equivalent to Matlab, without actually checking. Turns out it's more similar to the `evalin('base',...)` command.

Thanks again to Fengyand for giving another example of why the phrase "parse and eval" seems to have about the same effect on Julia programmers as the word "it" on [the knights who until recently said "NI"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZvsGdJP3ng). :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot agree with this answer. For one, instead of parsing a string, you should do `:($i = $m.$i)`. Furthermore, and perhaps more importantly, this doesn't actually evaluate anything locally—the eval is in global scope. Macros do not parse and evaluate strings; they transform expressions into other expressions that are inserted into the AST.

Comment: Thanks @FengyangWang , I was not aware of the `$` use outside of a string context, that's very useful to know! So are you saying this line wouldn't work inside a function? I admit I only tried it on the REPL. Also, why `$m.$i` rather than just `m.$i` ?

Comment: @FengyangWang thanks, I've updated my answer. As for the `$` approach, rather than provide a second-hand answer I thought you might like to demonstrate? :)

Comment: Hi @Tasos, you are right that it should be `m.$i`. There are a lot of places where `$` can be used in Julia; I am working on a Documentation entry with examples of using interpolation. For now, there is a brief [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Metaprogramming#Expression_interpolation) description here that may me useful.

Comment: Your learning here looks like something that could be adapted to a good documentation article

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge hahah, I'm procrastinating enough from my thesis as it is ... feel free to use the above if you'd like to take a stab at it :)